# Typo3 DatabaseQueryProcessor one-to-many relation

Tags: typo3, one-to-many

I want to join a table with a one-to-many relation in the DatabaseQueryProcessor. `table1.images` contains a comma separated list of image-uids from table2. e.g. `1,2,3`. In this example I would expect to get all 3 images as a result.

I tried:

```
dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = table1
        join = table2 on table1.images in (table2.uid)

        as = someValue
    }
}
```

But this only gives me the first image "1" but not the other two images.

How can a one-to-many relation be reflected in the DatabaseQueryProcessor?

I figured it out:

`join = table2 ON table1.images like concat('%', table2.uid , '%')` and

`join = table2 ON find_in_set(table2.uid, table1.images)` does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to check equality ("=") between a list and a single value. I wonder that you are getting a valid result at all and not an exception/error...

Have a look at SQL function for lists:

[IN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

```
join = table2 on table2.uid IN(table1.images)
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't exactly the solution, but good enough to find the solution. I added two possibilities to the question.